# Javascript runtime error: 'processPartInput' is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to retrieve data from a controller. This is a new twist on my Json error.  I added a function to the index.cshtml page and I try to add code to get the information from the controller.  I added a basic code to write a string to the textbox (all local) and that worked.  When I tried to call from the controller it doesn't matter what the code is I get this error:
[image: Error Message]
<sub>(source: [mousecreations.com](http://www.mousecreations.com/error.jpg))</sub>

I have tried the following with the same error.  Probably some other combinations that I have found in my search.

```
     $.getJSON(@Url.Action("GetIPAddress","getipaddress"),
     $.get(......)
     $.ajax(......)
```

The entire function

```
     function processgetip(event)
{
    // Within this function, make an AJAX call to get the IP Address
    $.getJSON(@Url.Action("GetIPAddress","getipaddress"), function (ip) {
        // When this call is done, your IP should be stored in 'ip', so
        // You can use it how you would like

        // Example: Setting a TextBox with ID "YourElement" to your returned IP Address
        $("#facility").val(ip);
    });
}
```

This error is different than any of the others so what in that process event would cause the other processes to be undefined?

Comment: What does `@Url.Action("GetIPAddress","getipaddress")` actually render in the page?

Comment: I think you need to put quotes around `@Url.Action()`, e.g. `$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetIPAddress","getipaddress")')`, as it should be a string in JavaScript

Comment: @Rhumborl not sure if it's different in ASP, but if that was a JS method it would (hopefully) return a string, and putting quotes around it would just make it a string

Comment: @JamesThorpe as I understand it should call the controller getipaddress and actionresult or Json GetIPAddress and populate the information in the textbox "facility"

Comment: Right click-> view source.  What is _actually there_?

Comment: @SterlingArcher asp.net mvc runs on the server. Calling `@Url.Action()` returns a _.NET_ string representing the url and just renders this in the page output sent to the client, i.e. `$.getJSON(http://www.google.com)`. It is generally not aware of the context it is being rendered into, particularly in Javascript blocks, so will not automatically add quotes to make it valid syntax. Saying that I don't know where this `processPartInput` is coming from, so worth seeing exactly what is rendered as James is suggesting

Comment: @Rhumborl ah ok that makes sense. Didn't know if it was parsed differently. So that's sort of like echoing a PHP variable -- still needs quotes. Makes sense

Comment: @SterlingArcher Yes, that's a good analogy

Comment: @ James Thorpe after viewing the source it does render something other than the code. `$.getJSON(/getipaddress/GetIPAddress, function (ip) {`